# Focusout event loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I've got a problem. I'm using jQuery 1.8.2. I want to react to a focusout event and reset the foucs to the element that was left under special conditions. Now i got this really simple codesnippet which gets caught in a loop in safari and I don't get it why this happens... Maybe you can help me, here's a really simple example:

JS:

```
$("#test").focusout( function () {
    alert("FocusOut event got triggered.");
    $("#test").focus();
});​
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test" />​
```

Maybe you want to try this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ds38v/3/  Just click into the input-box and leave it again.

Comment: What do you mean by "caught in a loop"? Which version and OS for Safari are you using?

Comment: The callback is being called agin and again and again... Mac OS 10.8.2 - Safari 6.0.2

Comment: Have you tried using console.log() instead of alert() ?

Comment: Yes. Removing the alert and use console.log() instead works. But my client wants an alert box. I got to fix that...

Comment: Does this fiddle work? (I do not have safari where I am) http://jsfiddle.net/ds38v/5/

Comment: Nice idea - thanks for that, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some browser differences concerning this issue. Therefore use a timeout to "simulate" it like a "leaveFocus"- and afterwards again a "focus"-Event:

```
$("#test").focusout( function () {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#test").focus();
    },1);
});​
```

Like this it's working.

I hope it helps...

Comment: I'm very sorry. In fact: your solution works very well. I just put the alert box in the wrong place. I've put it next to focus in the timeout-callback. Calling alert before the timeout is set does the trick. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: @tmuecksch, it wasn't my answer. But, it was obvious

Comment: @Alexander, After all - I noticed this still doesn't work propper. Just open this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ds38v/7/ in Safari or Firefox, click into the input-box and then change the program to something else and then change back. My Firefox (Nightly) hangs up and Safari is stuck in an alertbox loop again.