# Safari blur event loop after changing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I want to react to a blur event with a alert box. The idea is to validate the content and give feedback if the the value is not valid. I am not using the alert box for debugging, my client insists on that for giving the user feedback.
I had a similar here: (But this question is not redundant!) [Focusout event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126947/focusout-event-loop/14127043)

**So my current solution looks like this way**

HTML:

```
Type some stuff here:
<br>
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var doFocus = function () {
  $("#test").focus();
    console.log("do focus");
};

$("#test").blur(function () {
  console.log("Blur event got triggered.");
  alert("Blur event got triggered.");
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    doFocus();
  }, 1);
});
```

This works so far, but
**the Problem is:** if you open the site, click into the input field and then change the window. For example open a text editor, and then change back. The Safari gets stuck in a event loop (the callback is called again and again)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove this line:

```
alert("Blur event got triggered.");
```

Alert() should never been used in any blur event callback function.

**UPDATE**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PtGNX/)

```
var doFocus = function () {
  $("#test").focus();
    console.log("do focus");
};

var bluring = function(sender){
    $(sender).off('blur');
    console.log("Blur event got triggered.");
    alert("Blur event got triggered.");
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      doFocus();
      $(sender).on('blur',function(){bluring(this)});
    }, 1);
};

$("#test").blur(function(){bluring(this)});
```

Comment: Sounds like personal opinion. Any reliable source?

Comment: Yes - of course it does. But - as i mentioned before - my client insists on using alert(). I don't like that too.

Comment: "But - as i mentioned before" You didn't mentionned it before you edited your post, did you? This is a Safari behaviour. You cannot deal with it i think except by unbinding/rebinding blur event on your targeted element. Why on earth a client would ask for it? I dont get it. See my updated answer, should work on Safari.

Comment: A mentioned this from the start. You are invited to see the edit history ;) It works! Thanks for that. Yeah i know. My client asked for it because he got used to it. Nevermind. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "mentioned this from the start" so all my apologize

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add alert.The safari invokes 'activate' for a new window when still on old window.Added "time out" to enter proper time frame.Making alert conditional and changing the related variables before first alert occurs prevents the alert loop.

Example:

```
safari.application.addEventListener("activate", function(){
  //setTimeout prevents boundary complications
  setTimeout(
  function() {
    if (enabled) {
      var tab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab;
      if (curTab != tab) {
        curTab = tab;
        if (selectedTab != tab)
        alert('This is an alert!!');

      }
    }
  }
  ,1000);
},true);
```