# onBlur alert keeps firing in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, alert, onblur

I have the following HTML that displays an input textbox:

```
<html>
    <input type="text" onblur="javascript:alert('hello');this.focus();"/>
</html>
```

In IE and Chrome, clicking inside the textbox then outside of it shows the "hello" message then puts focus back on the textbox, which is desired.

In Safari, doing the same thing shows the "hello" message repeatedly.

Is this considered a bug in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's known issue in safari, i guess you need to do unbind of blur event before alert and bind it again after alert.

See here [Safari blur event loop after changing window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195365/safari-blur-event-loop-after-changing-window)